# Autoplay Embedded Youtube Video with Search Results

Tags: html, embed, autoplay

I'm a bit new to web development and am trying to embed a youtube video using a search keyword. I've been able to get this working, but I can't figure out how to set the videos to autoplay. Here's the embed code I have:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=search&list=nature video
```

I've tried adding &autoplay=1 to different parts of this string, as well as ?autoplay=1, but nothing worked. I would very much appreciate some help on this!

Answer (score 1):

I could never really figure out how to do this in the way I'm asking about above, but I eventually realized that the much, much smarter way of going about this is to use the [YouTube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

Comment: "The ability to queue a list of search results is deprecated and will no longer be supported as of 15 November 2020." - https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try like so:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/62Pkr1_HB5k/?listType=search&list=nature%20video&autoplay=1
```

I added only the first video ID and the `autoplay=1` parameter.

Comment: That definitely works, but the point of using a search term is that I can just use keywords to find the most recent hit for that video WITHOUT knowing the specific ID for that video (in the case of your example, the "62Pkr1_HB5k"). Does that make sense?